# For custom segue animation, how to tell the ViewController that it was animated?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiviewcontroller, segue

Here is my custom segue animation's code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.4 animations:^{
    destinationViewController.view.frame = targetFrame;
    buttonBarImageView.alpha = 0.0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [sourceViewController presentViewController:destinationViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
    [buttonBarImageView removeFromSuperview];
}];
```

Note in the above code that I pass `NO` for `animated` in `presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion`, because I'm using my custom animation and don't want to use any standard animation.

My destination view controller's method `viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` now should behave differently depending on the animation flag. In the VC, the flag decides if an additional own inner animation should be played or not. Various destination VCs exist and they have different inner animations. They are additional to the custom animation I'm talking about above.

However, I can not pass `YES` to the VC because I have to pass `NO` to `presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion`, which causes `NO` to be passed to the VC.

How can I prevent `presentViewController:...` from running an animation and still pass `YES` to the `viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` method of the VC?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility to check is passing `NO` to `super` when calling `[super viewWillAppear:]`

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:NO];
    //-- your own animation here
}
```

so you can pass `YES` to `presentViewController:`, but you override it when passing it to `super`.

If this does not work, I bet the only chance you have is passing `NO` to `presentViewController:` and add your own flag to the view controller so you can control whether it is custom animated or not.

Comment: Passing NO to the VC's superclass doesn't switch off the built-in standard animation. The animation takes place before viewWillAppear: is called.

Comment: interesting, thanks. then the only way I see is using your own flag so you can always pass `NO` to `presentViewController`…

Comment: Yes, if no other solution comes up, I will do that.